# Call PHP function from a button to delete row from a table

Tags: php, function, button, html-table

I have the following code inside PHP page that displays data from a table. In the last column I have a delete button that calls a function to delete the corresponding row from the table:

```
    // Print data from db
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions");
    echo "<table border='1' align='center'>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Multiple Choice Question</th>
    <th>Correct answer</th>
    <th>The Tip You Give</th>
    <th>Edit Question</th>
    <th>Delete Question</th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Question'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['Answer'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Help'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'><button type='button' onclick='edit_question()'><img src='images/Edit.png'></button></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'><button type='button' onclick='delete_question($row)'><img src='images/delete.png'></button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

the function is the following:

```
    <script>
    function delete_question(int $row_id)
    {
       var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this question?");
       if (r==true)
       {
          alert('<?php 
          $con=mysql_connect("localhost","stesia","stesia","stesia");
          // Check connection
          if (mysql_errno())
          {
             echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
          }
          mysql_query($con,"DELETE FROM questions WHERE ID='".$row_id."'");
          echo "You want to delete the " . $row_id['ID'] . " question!";
          echo "Question deleted!";
          mysql_close($con);
          ?>');
       }
       else
       {
          alert("Question not deleted!");
       }
    }
    </script>
```

The problem is that the function is called and displays the messages, but the row is not deleted (checked that in mysql also). I have tried some things but no luck. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: javascript is no PHP. do some ajax request.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this on client side. You should send an AJAX request to the server (PHP-) side to handle the deletion.

You can find related information here (though these are not showing the best practices, but it helps understanding the concepts):
[PHP - AJAX and MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know onclick only executes JavaScript Code. You could try to put your PHP function into a JavaScript function and execute this from the onclick tag